# Elastic search Query to Find Unanswered Questions

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I need to find the Unanswered Questions Total Count by using the Field "user_response" : [ ]". I am not getting any counts.

My Requirement is If User_Response is Blank or not available then that should be my Unanswered Questions

I wrote this below query But not Getting the Counts it is giving me 0

```json
GET/activity_tracking/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_response": "[ ]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Below are the Mapping Details

```json
{
  "user_response": {
    "properties": {
      "qid": {
        "type": "Keyword",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [exists function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference//current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) in your query

```json
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "user_response.qid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```